# Ubercart thumbnail saving in sites/default/files - Its messy - How would I get it to save in a specified folder?

Tags: ubercart, media

All of my ubercart thumbnail images are saving in sites/default/files and its getting way too messy. Is there a way I can tell them to save in a folder inside this directory? There is a media style for them and they get the prefix thmb_ but I cannot figure this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the [File (Field) Path Module:](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths)

> The File (Field) Paths module extends the default functionality of
>   Drupal's core Upload module, the FileField module and many other File
>   Upload modules by adding the ability to use node tokens in destination
>   paths and filenames.
>
> In simple terms, File (Field) Paths allows you to automatically sort
>   and rename your uploaded files using token based replacement patterns
>   to maintain a nice clean filesystem.

This can be applied to the Field holding the image